# Why does the compiler complain when I do not cast the result of malloc?

Tags: c, casting, compiler-errors, malloc

I am inspecting code that does not require explicitly casting result of malloc call but whenever I attempt to do this, the compiler throws an error.

i.e.

```
char *somevar;
somevar = malloc(sizeof(char) * n); //error
somevar = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * n); // ok
```

Comment: What error, exactly, are you getting?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This happens if you use C++ compiler instead of C compiler. As C++ requires explicit casting. 
The problem is not just with (un)casting `malloc` result, but any void pointer to other pointer.

Comment: Ok. This makes perfect sense. Since the framework I am using is written in C and I am creating a module written in C++ wrapped by extern calls, that I would be subject to C++ conventions, but the framework developers would not.

Comment: It's usually best to separate your C and C++ code into different modules. C++ compilers cannot compile C.

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to include the function prototype? For malloc(3), this is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```