# Why does "The C Programming Language" book say I must cast malloc?

Tags: c, casting, malloc, kernighan-and-ritchie

Today I reached page **167** of [The C Programming Language (second edition Brian W. Kernighan & Dennis  M. Ritchie)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628) and found that the author says I must cast `malloc`. Here is the part from the book:

> **7.8.5 Storage Management**
>
> The functions malloc and calloc obtain blocks of memory dynamically.
>
> ```
> void *malloc(size_t n)
> ```
>
> returns a pointer to n bytes of uninitialized storage, or NULL if the request cannot be satisfied.
>
> ```
> void *calloc(size_t n, size_t size)
> ```
>
> returns a pointer to enough free space for an array of n objects of the specified size, or NULL if
>       the request cannot be satisfied. The storage is initialized to zero.
>       The pointer returned by malloc or calloc has the proper alignment for the object in question,
>       but it must be cast into the appropriate type, as in
>
> ```
> int *ip;
> ip = (int *) calloc(n, sizeof(int));
> ```

I already know that `malloc` (and its family) returns type **void***, and [there are good explanations why not to cast `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

But my question is: Why does the book say I should cast it?

Comment: Because the book is old.

Comment: Because even the Sun has its dark spots, would be my answer. In other words, the book is wrong. It could be that the text predates the semantics for `void *`, and wasn't updated. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28460192/28169).

Comment: @Michi The book has many factual and typographic errors (google K&R errata), it is only somewhat compatible with the C90 standard, it does not address the current C standard nor any changes in the language since 1990. Worst of all it is filled with bad programming practice, bad style and code which relies on poorly-specified behavior. All of which you have to unlearn if you become a professional C programmer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: ...and contrast this with [Why does the compiler complain when I do not cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568301/why-does-the-compiler-complain-when-i-do-not-cast-the-result-of-malloc?rq=1) So, for C - don't cast. For C++ - cast, but don't use `malloc` because it's NOT C++ - except when you have to - but you shouldn't - except...AGGGHHHHHH!!!!! :-)

Comment: @Mandrill have you read my Question ? I had to edit my Question for you.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth is there a better/more relevant/ comparable text in comparison?

Comment: [Relevant page from the comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/malloc/cast.html)

Answer (score 229, accepted):

From http://computer-programming-forum.com/47-c-language/a9c4a586c7dcd3fe.htm:

> In pre-ANSI C -- as described in K&R-1 -- malloc() returned a `char *`
>   and it was necessary to cast its return value in all cases where the
>   receiving variable was not also a `char *`.  The new `void *` type in
>   Standard C makes these contortions unnecessary.
>
> To save anybody from the embarrassment of leaping needlessly to the
>   defence of K&R-2, I asked Dennis Ritchie for an opinion that I could
>   quote on the validity of the sentence cited above from page 142.  He
>   replied:
>
> > *In any case, now that I reread the stuff on p. 142, I think it's
> >         wrong; it's written in such a way that it's not just defensive
> >         against earlier rules, it misrepresents the ANSI rules.*

Comment: So the return type of malloc was **char** and not **void**. Thank you.

Comment: It's also mentioned in the errata http://web.archive.org/web/20150205025553/http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/cbook/2ediffs.html

Comment: You mustn't read this book without that errata printed on a paper(s) next to you.

Comment: @Lundin I will buy a new book with c11 standard.

Comment: @Michi - no, the return type was `char*`, not `char`. The two are vastly different.

Comment: @PeteBecker Sir, that was a typo, i know that and i did explained in my Question. about return type of malloc wich is **void***

Comment: @alk: exactly. By reading K&R you're listening to two gurus, which is ample ;-)

Comment: @Michi There was no `void` (or `void*`) in the original C language. `char*` was used as the generic pointer type then.

Comment: @SteveJessop Yes there are two but you need to check the guru best before date on both of them. Says 1990.

Comment: @KeineLust Would it be accurate to say that when malloc returns `char *`, the cast is actually required by the compiler to avoid a hard error?

Comment: @trognanders: Most compilers would report a warning rather than a hard-error in the absence of a cast, but having code compile cleanly can avoid the need to read through warning messages after each compilation to determine if any of them are reporting actual programmer mistakes.