# A better way to print each word in a newline without using libraries (apart from stdio.h)?

Tags: c, optimization

I'm trying to write a program that takes from the standard input stream a sentence, and based on the definition that a word is everything that is between "spaces"; "spaces" being the space character, tab character or newline character, so, for example, if the input stream is `hey      there this is      some test`, the output should be

```
hey
there
this
is
some
test
```

Here is my try:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

#define IS_SPACE(c) ((c) == ' ' || (c) == '\t' || (c) == '\n')

int main() {

    for(int c, inWord = FALSE; (c = getchar()) != EOF;)
        if(!IS_SPACE(c)) {
            putchar(c);
            inWord = TRUE;
        }
        else if(inWord) {
            putchar('\n');
            inWord = FALSE;
        }

    return 0;
}
```

But I don't like this approach because I am manually entering TRUE and FALSE to `inWord` when it can be automatically be done by `inWord = !IS_SPACE(c)`, but I don't know how to modify the code to make just one call to `IS_SPACE` without creating another temporal variable.

Comment: why don't just use [`isspace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace)?

Comment: @phuclv I'm actually doing the examples of Ritchie and Kernighan's book and I want to use only the things that they introduce until that point, so that I master the basics. That's why I don't want libraries.

Comment: You cannot do this without at least 1bit of *state*; to  decide on the new state, the program needs to remember the previous state. (but: you could cheat by using recursion)

Comment: ... but actually the state *bit* is only needed to decide what needs to be output.

Comment: K&R is so old that occasionally you'll find some odds [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32652213/995714). Probably it's better to use a modern C book

Comment: @phuclv Any good modern C book?

Answer (score 1):

```
int  my_spaces[256] = { 0 };
my_spaces[' '] = my_spaces['\t'] = my_spaces['\n'] = 1;
#define MY_SPACE(c) (my_sapces[c])
```

This is the core of how `isspace()` and friends are often implemented but with bits for `isspace()`, `isprint()`, ....

Old answer before your edit:
Look at `strtok`, though `strtok_r` is now my function of choice. Being built into C you can expect it to be optimized for the current implementation.

Comment: I actually don't want to use 'non-basic' libraries. I imported stdio because there is no way I could read the output any other way.

Comment: I edited the question title not to allow answers using string manipulation libraries.

Comment: See revised answer. And it should really use unsigned char.

Answer (score 1):

The bug is that it doesn't print the last '\n' if the text ends with nonspace.  Or maybe it is a feature? I did not fix it.

As to your question, you may do

```
for(int c, inWord=FALSE; (c = getchar()) != EOF;) {
    if(!IS_SPACE(c))
        putchar(c);
    else if(inWord)
        putchar('\n');
    inword = !IS_SPACE(c);
}
```

or even

```
for(int c, bPrevInWord = FALSE; (c = getchar()) != EOF;) {
    int bInWord = !IS_SPACE(c);
    if(bInWord)
        putchar(c);
    else if(bPrevInWord)
        putchar('\n');
    bPrevInWord = bInWord;
}
```

Comment: Not to be rude, but, your first example calls two times IS_SPACE, and your second one uses two temporal variables, which I explicitly excluded these.

Comment: Your action depends on whether `c` is nonspace AND whether the previous character is nonspace.  So you need either two temporal variables or two calls to IS_SPACE, you probably cannot avoid this.  (But, regarding two IS_SPACE calls, don't worry about efficiency, any compiler will optimize them away.)

Comment: That's exactly what I've thought, but maybe anyone of you had a different point of view. Apparently not. Thanks.

Comment: Actually I tried the 3 versions(mine and the two yours) and the compiler does not optimize yours, in total my code takes 32 lines of asm, and yours 43 and 37 respectively. https://godbolt.org/g/c55JR8